# How to properly tag a user using message.channel.send in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How to properly tag a user using message.channel.send in discord.js?

Here is my code:

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replacer) {
      return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replacer);
    }
    Bot.on('message', (message) => {
      var mcontent = message.content;
      var mauth = message.author;
      var mtag = mauth.tag;
      if (mcontent.includes("@p")) {
        var newmsg = replaceAll(mcontent, "@p", "@" + mtag);
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send(newmsg);
    });
```

And, it prints this: (By the way, I am hieyou1#6009) [with the message.delete(); disabled]

[image: tag not there]

No console logs are present when I execute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mentions from the bot is a little bit different. You need to use `<@userid>`.
But Discord.JS has a cleaner way to mention a user, instead of using `message.author.tag`, just use `message.author`. That will tag the user that sent the message.

```
message.channel.send(`Hey ${message.author} how's it going?`);
```

Or with the old way to concatenate the string:

```
message.channel.send("Hey " + message.author + " how's it going?");
```

Comment: And how do I get a user's ID from a user's tag?

Comment: Not sure why you need the user ID here, but: `message.author.id` @Mikey